# How can I get the Umbraco node path from a node id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, umbraco

I have an Umbraco tree node id in javascript.
How can I get the path of this node (ie. "-1,1045,1046,1175")?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
var tree = jQuery("#<%=DialogTree.ClientID%>").UmbracoTreeAPI();
var nodePath = tree.getPath(theNodeId);
```

But I can't find any reference for the Umbraco Tree API.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact no stock method for this in Umbraco.
I had to create my own webservice just for this. :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article from the Wiki:

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/backoffice-apis/tree-api-to-create-custom-treesapplications

I think it may get you on the right track.

Comment: I was already aware of this article, unfortunately it does not have any information regarding the javascript API.